# popup div location according to page space available

Tags: jquery

My HTML Page is Like this..

```
<a id="profile" href="#">Over Me to Show</a>
<div id="profile-view">
<span>Loading profile details...</span>
```

My Jquery Like this.

```
function ProfileView(){
            var height = 18;
            var left = 10;
            var Position = $('#profile').position();
            var SetPos = {
              top:(Position.top + height) + 'px',
              left:(Position.left + left) + 'px' 
            };
            $('#profile-view').css(SetPos);
            $('#profile-view').show();
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#profile').mousemove(function(){
              ProfileView();
           });
        });
```

When i move cursor over a link (over me to show) the #profile-view div should show.
its is working fine this div always shows on bottom of the link..

**I NEEDED if the div(#profile-view) full height or width cant shown Below the Link if it is overflows it should show above the link or right or left where space available to show all content in div.**

I don't no how to ask this in tech term.so please forget if anything wrong.

Comment: it would be enough if you clearly state what your result should be!

Comment: why don't you set a height and then make the overflow scroll

Comment: i can do if it full of text if i place a image inside the div it wont look nice.

Comment: why not, you can resize the image. Just show what you want. Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

you should get mouse position and increase or decrease this values to good position :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#profile').mouseover(function(event){
        var x = event.clientX;
        var y = event.clientY; 
        ProfileView(x, y);
   }).mouseout(function() {
            $('#profile-view').hide();
   })
});

function ProfileView(x, y){

            var height = 18;
            var left = 10;            
            var SetPos = {
              position : 'absolute',
              top: (x + height) + 'px',
              left: (y + left) + 'px' 
            };
            $('#profile-view').css(SetPos);
            $('#profile-view').show();
}
```

Comment: it working but showing div in very long distance when checking the link to bottom of the page..

Comment: see the facebook profile info div. it will change auto according to place of the profile name.

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the solution related in the following link..
[Demo Link](http://papermashup.com/experimental-jquery-tooltips/)

[Source Code](http://papermashup.com/experimental-jquery-tooltips/)